# how to manage variable inside of json value string?

Tags: karate

I have variable cardholder in my karate-config file.

I assigned it to the new **entrID** variable.

[image]The main thing that i am building JSON as a String..

```
 * def entrID = cardholder  
 * def requestContactHistoryAdd = 
   """ 
   { 
   "RequestBody": "{ \"ENTR_ID\" : \"entrID\", \"BHVR_ID\" : \"VRU\", }"
   } 
   """
```

Now how can i provide it inside of my json RequestBody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: since you seem to have a very badly designed API where the JSON has an embedded string (which looks like JSON).

Please note I am using a `string` type below: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

You can do this:

```
* def entrID = 'foo'  
* string temp = { "ENTR_ID" : "#(entrID)", "BHVR_ID" : "VRU" }
# note that you could have done this: 
# def temp = '{ "ENTR_ID" : "' + entrID + '", "BHVR_ID" : "VRU" }'
* def body = { RequestBody: '#(temp)' }
* print body
```

Which gives you:

```
08:17:25.671 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "RequestBody": "{\"ENTR_ID\":\"foo\",\"BHVR_ID\":\"VRU\"}"
}
```

Comment: I agree that it is ugly to build json as a string ... but the endpoint developed as follows..and not accept another way of the body ... that is the problem.
I saw this way in the documentation. I will try to play, maybe I can solve it somehow. thanks

Comment: @SaidYusifli ok, I completely changed my answer. does it work for you ? but please be more clear in your question next time.

Comment: wow this is really cool. Thank you
so if i declare my variable as a String not def. its returning with all \" \".

Answer (score 1):

i solved it also like this

```
 * def entrID = someValueFromSomeWhere
 * def bodyValue = "{ \"ENTR_ID\":\"" + entrID + "\", \"BHVR_ID\" : \"VRU\" }"
 * def requestContactHistoryAdd = 
   """ 
   { 
   "RequestBody": "#(bodyValue)"
   } 
   """
```

we can also do this way

```
 * def bodyValue = "{ \"ENTR_ID\":\"" + someValueFromSomeWhere + "\", \"BHVR_ID\" : \"VRU\" }"
 * def requestContactHistoryAdd = 
  """
  { 
  "RequestBody": "#(bodyValue)" 
  }
  """
```